# How to use random effects in glmer?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, prediction

The model is a mixed logistic model with random effects.

Suppose I have a database with 10000 users of a website, each user has his own unique id, the data is collected for 100 last sessions of the user, each session has its number (from 1 - 100) - sessions_sequence and same for every user.

I have performed full outer join and added a column with ids of the users corresponding to each row, so now my database has the id column which shows to which user the data is related.

My aim is to make a prediction whether a user will purchase the membership or not.

After trying to perform glmer(), my PC takes too much time to process the request and I am not sure if I understand the whole concept correctly. I am using random effect on (1 | user_id) and (1 | session_sequence). My response variable is whether the user already has the membership or not (0/1).

```
m2 <- glmer(is_member ~ click + (1 | session_sequence) + (1 | user_id),
          family = binomial(link="logit"),
          control = glmerControl(optimize = "bobyqa"),
          data = dfs)
```

I can add more predictors if needed, but I was trying to avoid collinearity because "click" represents 4 other potential predictors in some way.

Previously, when trying to run:

```
m2 <- glmer(is_member ~ click + (1 | user_id),
          family = binomial(link="logit"),
          control = glmerControl(optimize = "bobyqa"),
          data = dfs)
```

I got this error:

```
Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev, : 
(maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.